# Input string was not in correct fromat: TimeSpan DisplayFormat

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-annotations

I want to display TimeSpan on my view with only days, hours and minutes.
If days or hours are 0 i dont want to show them.
I tried many combinations but nothing works

**Example: (Input string was not in correct format exception)**

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{hh:mm}")]
    [Display(Name = "Time [min]")]
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
```

**I also tried:**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{%h:%m}")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}")]
```

**This just shows format string instead of numbers:**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"hh/:mm")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "hh:mm")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"d\.h\:mm\:ss")]
```

Most of them dont have days just because i wanted to make it work first with just hours and minutes.
How to properly set `DisplayFormat` annotation for `TimeSpan`?

---

**@Edit:**

Ok, i somehow figured it out, but how to show all hours (more than 24) OR show days but hide them if it's 0?

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:%d} {0:%h}h {0:mm}min")]
```

Comment: Try `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]` or (equivalent) `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm"})]`

Comment: If i dont include { } then it just shows hh\\:mm instead of numbers and with curly braces its "input string was not in correct format"

Comment: @VillageTech second format string `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]` has syntax errors but the first one is ok

Comment: You are right, there is mistake between '"' and '}' chars. This should be: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]`